# Complete the given sentence

Tags: tenses

Fill in the gap in the sentence given below:

See, its raining. It ______________________(will be/ becomes/ is going to be) flooding soon.

I think the answer is will be. But I am not sure about it. Can anyone explain.?

Answer (score 1):

Is going to be flooding soon is fair to use because 'see, it's raining' implies present continuous tense, so is going to be 'is fair to use.